# Create empty table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, create-table

i want to create a simple table inside a database in postgresql.
From the Documentation i have `CREATE TABLE will create a new, initially empty table in the current database. The table will be owned by the user issuing the command.`
With this command

```
CREATE TABLE *table_name*;
```

I thought i get a new empty table.But psql throws `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"`. When i user an empty argument list like:

```
CREATE TABLE *table_name*();
```

psql tells me that the table was created through

```
postgres=# create table *table_name*();
CREATE TABLE
```

But \l shows is not showing the newly created table. And its also not possible to login with psql -d *table_name* -U *user_name*. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you really need a table with no columns? One usually calls an *empty* table the one with no records. The one without columns is kind of odd.

Comment: You got to add columns. Or since you use rails, do it with migrations. You'd want to use raw SQL if you had an existing DB you wanted to integrated with.

Comment: rails can create DB for you as well via `rake db:create` or something.

Comment: Oh great i did not know that. I ll definatly check that out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have a table with no columns, and even with some rows in it:

```
CREATE TABLE nocolumn (dummy INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
    ;

INSERT INTO nocolumn(dummy) VALUES (1);

ALTER TABLE nocolumn
        DROP COLUMN dummy;

\d nocolumn

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM nocolumn;
```

---

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
ALTER TABLE
   Table "tmp.nocolumn"
 Column | Type | Modifiers 
--------+------+-----------

 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Overly complicated approach. It's enough to just `CREATE TABLE mytable ();`.

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be confusing the terms *database* and *table*

> But `\l` is not showing the newly created table.

Of course `\l` will not show you that table, because `\l` will list *databases* not relations. To see all tables you need to use `\d` or `\dt`.

> And its also not possible to login with `psql -d table_name -U user_name`

Of course this is not possible, because the `-d` parameter is used to specify a *database*, not a *table*

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why other answers suggest to create a table with a column and then ignore that column. It is certainly possible, but it seems different from what you tried to do.

It seems you have to use parenthesis:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE t ();
CREATE TABLE
```

To insert a row:

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO t DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT 0 1
```

To count the rows you inserted:

```
postgres=# SELECT FROM t;
--
(2 rows)
```

You can't delete a single rows, because all rows are equal. But to completely empty the table, you can use `DELETE` without `WHERE`, or `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

You can find more info here: [PostgreSQL: Tables without columns](https://sql-bits.com/postgresql-tables-without-columns/).

That said, I have to say that I understand "empty table" as "table without rows", not necessarily without columns.

Answer (score 1):

An hour ago i suggested to add at least one column like this:

```
create table tab1 (columnname varchar(42) not null)
```

---

But this seems to be **not necessary** as a commentator just told. (I consider to keep the wrong answer here instead of deleting it, to prevent that others suggest the same)

Comment: This is not really an answer, unless you actually add in a code block that shows you how to add columns,  at best this is just a sarcastic dig at the op, and you can do this in the comments, without putting it out as an answer

Comment: I just tested to create a columless table with a database client for mixed server types (HeidiSQL) it always prevents generating tables without columns. Anyway I come to no idea of a usefull use of tables containing no colums that enables them to ever carry data in it. But thanks for the downvote.. 2 more an I can earn the peer pressure badge -.-

Comment: I've added a code block adding a column... I was not aware of the rule that answers on Stackoverflow.SE must contain codeblocks always. Sorry.

Comment: There is a rule that an answer, is an answer.  If you ask a question, Do people just answer with "  You are doing it wrong "   answers?

Comment: also I did not downvote,  If i downvote, I say, and I don't really downvote unless it is really terrible

Comment: the answer was... "add a column and it should work" ... what makes this a "you are doing wrong" thing?

Comment: You can actually create a table without columns in Postgres. `create table empty();` works just fine.